Filtering Microsoft Graph API with a guid
I want to get only assigned members for a specific role for an application. I have the following query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals('3880b540-17bf-470c-929d-45cd14ddca72')/AppRoleAssignedTo?$filter=AppRoleId eq 'fb9c780e-9fad-47e3-b231-cf4ab958a371'

But I get an error:

Invalid filter clause: A binary operator with incompatible types was
detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' for operator
kind 'Equal'.

From what I can tell they are both GUIDs.
If I remove the quotes, I get this error instead:

Invalid filter clause appRoleId: System.Guid

What am I missing?
(I've seen this: Microsoft Graph Api: Filter by GUID value, but the solution there was my starting point...)
[Update]
I have found this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1517028/filter-on-guid-for-approleassignedto-principalid-d?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1436291
It seems that the behavior misled others too.
It is stated in the documentation that OData filtering can be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters
And still, it seems not to be.
I really would like to get an authoritative statement about this. Will this be addressed at any point in time? Fetching all and filtering on the client side is a workaround but far from ideal. But if that's the intended use, both the documentation and the message is wrong IMHO.

It's either broken or not supported. According to the doc, resourceId should support filtering. Are you able to filter data at least by resourceId?

I will give it a try. But that will probably take time, as this was my last attempt before my holiday.

Agree with @user2250152, check this MS Doc. Filter on appRoleId is not supported.  As of now, you can only fetch full set of results then filter them client-side using any programming language like this https://i.imgur.com/5enP2yg.png

@Sridevi Well, according to the docs it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters I don't see any remark on the page you have linked that it is not. BTW: I get the same error for any GUID property.

@ZorgoZ Note that, doc stated it supports OData query parameters that can be $count, $select, $top, $orderby NOT $filter in particular.
To know which property supports filter, you can check this MS Doc properties that mentions "Supports $filter" in property's description like this .

For listing app role assignments, only principalDisplayName and resourceId properties supports $filter query parameter.

As you are saying "BTW: I get the same error for any GUID property.", did you try listing app role assignments by filtering on resourceId GUID property? If Yes, please include how you are filtering?

I have service principal having below App roles assigned to few users like this:

To fetch these details via Microsoft Graph API, you can make use of below request:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/spObjId/appRoleAssignedTo


But when I tried to filter the response by appRoleId GUID, I too got same error like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/spObjId/appRoleAssignedTo?$filter=appRoleId eq 'xxxxxxxxxxx'


Note that, MS Doc stated it supports OData query parameters that can be $count, $select, $top, $orderby NOT OData filtering $filter in particular.
To know which property supports filter, you can check this MS Doc properties that mentions "Supports $filter" in property's description like this:

As of now, only principalDisplayName and resourceId properties supports $filter query parameter on listing app role assignments endpoint.
If you are facing issue while filtering with GUID, make sure not to enclose GUID value in quotes and include advanced query parameter as mentioned here.
In my case, I ran below query to list app role assignments of service principal by including advanced query parameters to filter with resourceId GUID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/spObjId/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq 0xxxxx8-1xx9-4xxx-3xxxxxx6&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: Eventual


Reference:
How to $filter appRoleAssignments based on appRoleId? - Stack Overflow by Ahsan Habib
